# How do I change the regExp in a Spring WebFlow Project with Dojo you change field size

Tags: regex, spring, spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

How do I change the regExp in a Spring WebFlow Project with Dojo you change field size. I am working on a Spring WebFlow project with Dojo and I would like to change the regExp in Dojo to check that the user entered a name that is bigger then 1 digit and smaller then 10 digits. can someone please help me out with this,.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>



<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 @import url("<c:url value="/resources/dojo/resources/dojo.css"/>");
 @import url("<c:url value="/resources/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>");
</style>     

<script djconfig="parseOnLoad: true"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC - Web Flow Example</title>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <h2>Field Size Test</h2>

    <form:form commandName="customer" id="customer">
        <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey"
            value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
        <div id="container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><b>Name:</b></td>
                    <td valign="top"><form:input path="name" class="value" /> <script
                            type="text/javascript">
                        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                            elementId : "name",
                            widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
                            widgetAttrs : {
                                promptMessage : "Please Enter Your Name from 1 to 10 digits",
                                invalidMessage : "A 1 to 10 digit value is required.",
                                required : true,
                                regExp : "[0-9]{10}"

                            }
                        }));
                    </script> <br />
                        <p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({
                elementId : 'submit',
                event : 'onclick'
            }));
        </script>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this `[0-9]{1,10}` it means between 1 and 10 digits (10 included) it's good for a phone number or something like this.
if you are talking about letter too, I suggest `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}` or if you want only letters  `[a-zA-Z]{1,10}`